# python selenium 3.0 - Firefox 47.0.1 installed in default location is not identified. (geckodriver)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Following is my environment:

1. OS : Windows 10 - 64 (Home edition)
2. Browser : Firefox 47.0.1 (32 bit)
3. Python : 2.7.10.12 (64 bit)
4. selenium : 3.0.1
5. Geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64.zip

Firefox is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox`.

geckodriver.exe is placed in `C:\Python27\Scripts` location.

Following is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples1.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

My question is that though firefox is installed in default location, webdriver could not be able to find it and throws the error.

Note: when I explicitly specify the Firefox binary location as follows, it is working.

```
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that Python couldn't find the function FirefoxBinary directly.

I encountered a similar problem. Solved it by giving reference to the function:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
```

Later found that the solution is already available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208762) (indirectly).

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. after restarting the machine, working as expected i..e., launched the browser from default location even without specifying the location using Firefox Binary location. I am sure it is not import problem.

Comment: I have no idea what this means: "Python couldn't find the function FirefoxBinary directly"... but this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Restarting my machine solved the issue.** (May be required if you keep the `geckodriver.exe` in one of the `PATH` locations.

Not sure if it was the real issue that needs to be solved, but one of the variable.

---

**Little Background to geckodriver.exe and Firefox version support:**

From `geckodriver` github page:

```
Firefox 47 is explicitly not supported
```

So, If you want to use `Firefox 47.0.1` version, use `Firefox driver` but not `geckodriver`.

1. In case of selenium 2.53, you don't need to do any additional things (no need to setup `geckodriver` as `selenium 2.53` uses `Firefox driver` by `default`).
2. In Selenium 3.0, we must set `geckodriver` path (as `geckodriver` is the `default` driver for `Firefox` in `Selenium 3.0`) using `System.setProperty` and set `marionette` to `false`, so `geckodriver` capabilities will be disabled and default Firefox driver is used.

**example code:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities d = new DesiredCapabilities();
d.setCapability("marionette", false);  // to disable marionette, by default true
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(d);
```

References:

1. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#supported-firefoxen
2. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/224
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658421/2575259