# chrome browser is opened when firefox driver is used

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium, I am initializing a `firefox` driver but, the `chrome` driver is initialized and `chrome` browser is opened.

Had I configured default settings anywhere? What could be the problem..Sorry for the dumb question.But, I got no clues.Please help.

Here goes my code,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Aon
{
public static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/ranganah/Downloads/Softwares/Selenium/geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hari");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
   }
   }
```

For the screen shot: https://postimg.org/image/ncyg2o9l5/

Comment: Really?? provided code opens chrome browser instead??

Comment: Check if you don't open Chrome from some other place.

Comment: Yes.With the errors below.Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on port 11635
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: Could you share how you are defining `driver`?? I think this is not full code..

Comment: @ Guy: This is the only code in the only class of a package..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Here it is,main thread updated

Comment: Could you share screenshot as well where have you written these code...??

Comment: Instead of firefox,can you try opening IE and check what happens?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj The same thing happens if ie driver is used.

Comment: This is not possible, literally. can you add the screenshots of Chrome browser which is being launched? And the execution happened without any issues? check for errors in eclipse console

Comment: @SaurabhGaur,Naveen, Please find SS in the main thread.

Comment: @harinarayan I think, you need to log a bug on selenium website..Thanks..

Comment: Are you running it as "'Run As -> Java Application"? also, tell us the versions of Firefox, Chrome, Java, Selenium, Geckodriver versions

Comment: @Naveen Yes, I am running it as "'Run As -> Java Application".Not working even if it is executed as a testng test.Selenium 3.0.1, Gecko driver 0.11.1, firefox 47.0.1.Note: I have been using only chrome for a while in my tests.

Comment: Geckodriver does not support FF47, following their [Github info](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver). `Firefox 47 is explicitly not supported.` I would try upgrading to FF48, at least. I have tried with FF50 and didn't find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you renamed `chromedriver.exe` to `geckodriver.exe`

Download `geckodriver.exe` from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and add it to the path and try.

---

Observed that when we rename `chromedriver.exe` to `geckodriver.exe`, though you create an instance of `Firefox/InternetExplorer Driver`, it will launch `Chrome` browser.

Comment: Thats a good try naveen. But, seems like its not the case..:)

Comment: @harinarayan, have you tried it out? Firefox 47.0.1 is the version from which geckodriver support. so, it might be an issue with the geckodriver. I suggest following actions to perform in the listed manner 1. Restart the machine and run. If not working, 2. Upgrade the browser to the latest one (50.0.2 as of now) and use the latest geckodriver and try. similar issue I have faced. more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269229/python-selenium-3-0-firefox-47-0-1-installed-in-default-location-is-not-identi

Comment: Firefox 47 is explicitly not supported by geckodriver.more details here  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#supported-firefoxen & https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/224

Comment: @ Naveen, Tom The problem occurs only for the specific class and package. When I create a new project, it works fine with same firefox and gecko driver.

Comment: Are you using any framework like JUnit or TestNG to run your tests (the specific class)?

Comment: No, as mentioned earlier, its a simple java class

Comment: I am not sure what is the reason, you can continue with the new project. right?